# "message not understood" failure in Pharo Monticello

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, monticello

I am running Pharo 8.0.0 64-bit stable, build 1124.  When I use Monticello to save a package (to a local directory or a remote repository) an error comes up as I'm entering the log message:

```
instance of MCSaveVersionDialog does not understand #selectClassOrMetaClass
```

I'd show some of the stack trace but cut and paste between windows on Fedora core 33 isn't working for me.

Can anybody spare me the pain of digging into Pharo to find out what's going on? (Squeak Monticello also fails during log entry, but for a different, and slightly more comprehensible, reason.)

Ok, pictures, I've got pictures.

Monticello right before invoking Save:

[image: The invocation in Monticello]

Adding the log message "Created":

[image: Entering the log message]

And two letters into the log message things go boom:

[image: stack trace]

The miscreant itself:

[![bad code, bad][4]][4]

For those worried about using Monticello to save to the local file system, saving to an Internet-resident server

[image: saving to squeaksource]

causes the same failure

[image: failed again]

Comment: Poking around on the Web for an answer is leading me to believe that Monticello is obsolete, at least for storing code.  The current standard of practice for code management in Pharo seems to be Iceberg + GitHub.  Nevertheless, if Monticello's in the image, it should be in working condition.

Comment: Perhaps a photo showing the stack might help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next thing to try is of course the current build (today 1145) instead of the stable. In PharoLauncher you can find that by selecting a build from Pharo 8.0 (stable), instead of Official distributions. Or download it [directly](http://files.pharo.org/image/80/)That will likely solve your problem, as I found [a description referring to an `openMenu` issue](https://github.com/pharo-project/pharo/pull/6427). The builds are posted to [the pharo developers list on forum](http://forum.world.st)

Comment: Moving to build 1145 fixed the problem.  Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

One thing that is wrong is that you haven't selected a repository to save in. The package cache is not used for that. The package cache is supposed to get a copy of the package you save. Add a repository, file repository local (or create one on squeaksource or ss3)

Comment: Thanks for your reply to my question.  Saving to somewhere else in the file system causes the same failure, as does saving to squeaksource.